# Android ImageView Nearest Neighbor

Tags: android, image-processing, imageview

I'm creating an app that requires pixel art to be displayed from the web.

On iOS, I can set a UIImageView to have it's magnification filter to

`imageView.layer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest`

And everything takes care of itself.

However I cannot seem to do anything about this in Android. How would I change the magnification method of the images that I can hand to Android's imageView?

Answer (score 6):

This is done via the `BitmapDrawable`'s `Paint`, rather than the view, using [setFilterBitmap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setFilterBitmap(boolean)):

```
myBitmapDrawable.getPaint().setFilterBitmap(false);
myImageView.setImageDrawable(myBitmapDrawable);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! ...and I always thought it was way more complicated...